# Can't open received amr/jgp file from socket on android

Tags: java, android, sockets, jpeg, amr

To send and receive file via socket over Wifi I have used following code...

### Client side :

```
Socket socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
            int bufferSize=socket.getReceiveBufferSize();
            InputStream in=socket.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(in);
            String fileName = clientData.readUTF();
            System.out.println(fileName);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/"+fileName);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int read;
            while((read = clientData.read(buffer)) != -1){
                output.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }


            //close every thing
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            socket.close();
```

Server side:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/sdcard/test.amr");

            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[8092];
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
            OutputStream os;
            try {
                os = socket.getOutputStream();
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
                dos.writeUTF(file.getName());
                dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);
                int read;
                while((read = dis.read(mybytearray)) != -1){
                    dos.write(mybytearray, 0, read);

                }
                os.flush();

                os.close();
                socket.close();
```

At this point I am receiving file 'test.amr' from server without change of its original size.
But when I try to play the file in client device it can't be played.

Note : mp3, avi and txt file received using above code can be opened and played perfectly.

Please suggest how to solve this issue.

Comment: `dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);`. Why would you send that buffer length? Your cient isnt reading it either.

Comment: Please describe it little more elaborately @greenapps

Comment: It was a question. Why do you have that code line? You should elaborate! Explain your code.

Comment: Thanks, its working now @greenapps

Comment: Please remove your answer. And just tell in a comment that you removed the line.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved the above problem by just removing 
dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length); 
line form server code...
as per suggestion of greenapps.

My revised server code is:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/sdcard/test.amr");

        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[8092];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
        OutputStream os;
        try {
            os = socket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
            dos.writeUTF(file.getName());
            int read;
            while((read = dis.read(mybytearray)) != -1){
                dos.write(mybytearray, 0, read);

            }
            os.flush();

            os.close();
            socket.close();
```

Comment: You should not have posted this as an answer yourself. And you should first have answered my questions. That the line had to be removed you could read from my first comment already. You found help but do not give credit in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing the buffer size as a `long` but you're not reading it. So the `long` is being read as part of the image. As writing your sending buffer size has no conceivable relevance to the receiver, you should remove the  `writeLong(mybytearray.length)` call from the sender.